# How to take the gradient of this function similar to quadratic form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euler-lagrange-equation

This question is  about  Lagrangian multi-rigid body dynamics equation.

forward kinematics is  $$ x=G(q) $$

first-order differential forward kinematics equation is $$ \dot x= J(q) \dot q $$

Lagrangian expressed in Cartesian space is
$$L(x,\dot x) = T(x,\dot x) - U(x) $$

Lagrangian equation expressed in Cartesian space
$$  \frac{d}{dt} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}) -  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}  = F $$

the kinetic energy in Cartesian space

$$T(x,\dot x) = \frac{1}{2} \dot x^T  \Lambda (x) \dot x $$

$\Lambda (x)$ is a symmetric matrix

the kinetic energy in Joint space

$$T(q,\dot q) = \frac{1}{2} \dot q^T  A(q) \dot q $$

$ A(q)$ is a symmetric matrix

$$ \Lambda (x) = J(q)^{-T}  A (q)   J(q) ^{-1} $$

How to get $\frac{\partial T(x, \dot x)}{\partial x}$ i.e. $\nabla T(x, \dot x)$ with $ A(q), J(q) $
Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

the answer is in [lecture](https://www.ce.cit.tum.de/fileadmin/w00cgn/rm/pdf/AdvancedRoboticManipulation.pdf) page 58 `Chapter 4 Operational Space Framework` `Joint Space/Operational Space Relationships`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the definition
$T 
=
\frac12 
\dot{\mathbf{q}}: \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q}) \dot{\mathbf{q}}
$
and the fact that
$\mathbf{J}^{-1} d\mathbf{x}=d\mathbf{q}$.
For convenience, the dot product will be denoted with the double colon notation.

Using differentials, it holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
dT 
&=&
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})\dot{\mathbf{q}}: d\dot{\mathbf{q}}+
\frac12 
\dot{\mathbf{q}}: (d\mathbf{A}) \dot{\mathbf{q}} \\
&=&
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})\dot{\mathbf{q}}:
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\mathbf{J}^{-1}
\right) d\mathbf{x}+
\frac12 
\dot{\mathbf{q}}: 
\left(
\sum_k
\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial q_k}
d q_k
\right)
\dot{\mathbf{q}} \\
&=&
\left[
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\mathbf{J}^{-1}
\right)
\right]^T
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})\dot{\mathbf{q}}:
d\mathbf{x}
+
\sum_k
l_k dq_k
\end{eqnarray*}
with
$
l_k
=
\frac12
\dot{\mathbf{q}}:
\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial q_k}
\dot{\mathbf{q}}
$ and the relation
$
\sum_k
l_k dq_k
=
\mathbf{l}(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}}):d\mathbf{q} 
=
\mathbf{l}(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}}):\mathbf{J}^{-1} d\mathbf{x}
=
\mathbf{J}^{-T} \mathbf{l}(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}}): d\mathbf{x}
$.

The gradient is thus as requested given by
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
\left[
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\mathbf{J}^{-1}
\right)
\right]^T
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{q})\dot{\mathbf{q}}
+
\mathbf{J}^{-T} \mathbf{l}(\mathbf{q},\dot{\mathbf{q}})
$$